# How to change User::Model In Laravel with User Auth in Firebase

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Recently I have make Laravel auth with `composer require laravel/ui`and I can edit/create user with MySQL where as  auth users for Firebase .

I also can create/edit Users for each database and everything is OK for now, but what I just want is to create a new user form Laravel *{RegisterController}*

I can create the user with Firebase, but what value or what object shall I return to be compatible with Laravel auth?

**Create User with Laravel**

```
 return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
```

**Create User with FireBase**

```
 $userProperties = [
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'emailVerified' => false,
            'password' =>  Hash::make($data['password']),
            'displayName' =>  $data['name'],
        ];
        $user = new AuthController();
        return $user->Create_User($userProperties);
```

**AuthController Class**

```
  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->serviceAccount=ServiceAccount::fromValue(__DIR__.'/FirebaseKey.json');
        $this->firebase=(new Factory)->withServiceAccount($this->serviceAccount);
        $this->auth=$this->firebase->createAuth();
    }
public function Create_User($userProperties=[]){
        return  $this->auth->createUser($userProperties);
    }
```

*return value with dd(); -->User(Laravel)*

[image: aaaa]]

*return value with dd(); -->User(Firebase)*

[image: aaaa]]